# In YouTube, how to filter comments - by popularity. Because it does not work anymore

Tags: youtube

YouTube forcefully stealing attention and time, by not letting anymore to filter comments by popularity. Instead button function now is popular comments mixed with not popular more then not I guess. How to bypass that?
P.s if possible leave credit for places you yourself learnt.